# customize the apiary console drop-down menu

Tags: apiary.io

I want to customize the apiary console's drop-down menu. Here is my use-acases

I have added the `HOST` field in apiary blueprint which is a url of a staging server. In console, by default, the drop-down menu shows `production` name for this url.

1). Is it possible change the `production` in console drop-down menu to `staging` ?

2). Is it possible to remove the "Debugging Proxy" from drop-down menu ?

Comment: This can be done with Apiary Embed (Modifying Hosts): https://help.apiary.io/tools/embed/#script  -- and yes, only on paid versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Disclaimer: I work for apiary.io] It is possible to customise the dropdown menu to some extent and this is a part of our paid plans. Feel free to contact support [at] apiary [dot] io for more information on this.